# Duplicate entry error while calling commit method in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, concurrency, exception

I tried to call same API concurrently, that is creating  some rows in hibernate join table in db and there is  some unique  constraint on some column.

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
...
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CustomerProduct", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cp_customer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cp_product_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    @OrderBy("id")
    private Set<Product>   products = new HashSet<Product>(0);

...
}

@Entity
public class Product{

....
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "CustomerProduct", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cp_product_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "cp_customer_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Set<Customer> customers = new HashSet<Customer>(0);

....

}
```

cp_product_id+cp_customer_id is unique key in CustomerProduct table(Hiberante join table). I am getting exception from this table.

```
 fun()
    {
    Product productDO = getById(....);
    // DO to DTO
    for (Customer cr : customerList) {
                    productDTO.customers.add(cr);
                }
   // DTO to DO
    saveOrUpdate()
    commit()
    }
```

In first call I  got proper response. In second call I got error in commit line, it's showing duplicate entry. That's was expected because the same key has  been saved in DB, but how can I avoid  this error. 
Because there is already check for duplicate keys before saveOrUpdate. 
Does saveOrUpdate method persist data in DB, or only commit store data in db.

Please tell me any good idea to avoid this error. I am new to hibernate, don't have much idea about saveorupdate and commit.

Why hibernate optimistic locking couldn't handled this?

Comment: If you avoided that error, you would have a duplicate in your database, and you don't want that. So this error is a good thing. Just try to avoid it as much as you can by checking first, and deal with it if you're unlucky enough to get it anyway due to a race condition.

Comment: saveOrUpdate() does not issue an update or insert on db but when you call commit() your persitence context is flushed and udate or insert queries are invoked

Comment: @Zulfi Yes that was the my doubt. So I think here problem is whenever I am checking from db there was no such key, but when I go for commit of second call, before that first has been committed. So how can I provide check.